# Is there an equivalent to ReverseProxyPass for Apache in Traefik?

Tags: traefik

I have setup Traefik to work in Docker Swarm mode. I have deployed Portainer into the cluster with the following command:

```
docker service create                            \
                                                 \
   --label "traefik.port=9000"                   \
   --label "traefik.docker.network =traefik-net" \
   --label "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:`hostname -f`;PathPrefixStrip:/portainer" \
   --label="traefik.backend=portainer" \
                                       \
   --network traefik-net               \
   --constraint "node.role == manager" \
   -p 9000:9000                        \
   --mount "type=bind,src=/var/run/docker.sock,dst=/var/run/docker.sock" \
   --name portainer \
   portainer/portainer
```

As can be seen I have configured Traefik, through the use of labels, to proxy the request for `/portainer` to the Portainer service. However the links that are served by Protainer are from `/` as it does not know it is being proxied, so the application does not work as Traefik does not know how to route each link.

I am trying to avoid having to change the deployments of services to work with Traefik as I want it to be transparent.  To that end is it possible to get Traefik to rewrite the links from the service like `ReverseProxyPass` for Apache does?

I know that Traefik now sets the `X-Forwarded-Prefix` but I am not sure how to get things like Portainer to use it out of the box or indeed other services that are installed from the Docker Store for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My mistake, this is working.  I was omitting the trailing `/` from the request. When I add this, it all works.

So now I call:

http://dummy.localhost/portainer/

Comment: Fine for you that it works now :-), but what did you exactly do? Did you modify your docker command? Did you modify the request? And if so: In which way?

Comment: @eventhorizon He modified his PathPrefixStrip: value to have a / at the end, as he said in his answer. The original does not have the /

Comment: It's still annoying that the trailing / is required when hitting the page though

Comment: Anyone know how to redirect `/portainer` to `/portainer/` so the page always works properly?

Comment: @JoePhillips https://stackoverflow.com/a/61976953/667767 This is the way.