# Cannot access Portainer when trailing "/" is missing. Is it possible to get the same behavion as Nginx proxy_pass?

Tags: traefik

I'm trying to setup Traefik to replace my Nginx reverse proxy setup.
I have my domain setup like this:
 - I can access different services using http://example.com and detecting which service I should proxy to, by using subpath.

[image: Nginx config of reverse proxy]

I tried to recreate same setup with Traefik. First by using ReplacePathRegex and then StripPrefix. My api requests work fine, but when I try to use Portainer, requests made from web browser omit /portainer part which causes web ui to break.

For example:
I make request to http://example.com/portainer.
I get response and then consecutive requests should be made like this: `http://example.com/portainer/vendor1.css`
and instead it makes request like this: 
`http://example.com/vendor1.css`

Is there any way to setup Traefik behavior to exactly match Nginx `proxy_pass`?

I found this post that gives me a partial solution: [Is there an equivalent to ReverseProxyPass for Apache in Traefik?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246098/is-there-an-equivalent-to-reverseproxypass-for-apache-in-traefik). Portainer seems to be working when I make request to http://example.com/portainer/ by adding "/" to the end.
I tried to fix it with `forceSlash`, but it did not make any change

[image: Current setup for Portainer with Traefik]

Is it possible to make it work with or without trailing "/"?

This is how requests look like in `/portainer` and `/portainer/`:
[image: /portainer request]

[image: /portainer/ request]

This is my current Traefik configuration (I'm only using Docker):
[image: Traefik configuration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: https://community.containo.us/t/middleware-to-add-the-if-needed/1895

This is what I had to add to `labels` in my portainer container to make it work:

```
- traefik.http.middlewares.strip-prefix.chain.middlewares=strip-prefix-1,strip-prefix-2
- traefik.http.middlewares.strip-prefix-1.redirectregex.regex=^(https?://[^/]+/[a-z0-9_]+)$$
- traefik.http.middlewares.strip-prefix-1.redirectregex.replacement=$${1}/
- traefik.http.middlewares.strip-prefix-1.redirectregex.permanent=true
- traefik.http.middlewares.strip-prefix-2.stripprefixregex.regex=/[a-z0-9_]+
```

It is not ideal solution as I think there should be an easier way to achieve it, but for the time being it satisfies my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Stripprefix middleware is for removing prefixes from the path before forwarding the request. According to your configuration, everything after `/portainer` and `/portainer` itself will be stripped.
In your case, it will also remove the trailing slash. If you need to forward `/` to the Portainer, then you need to use `portainer` (without slash) as to configure the prefix of stripprefix middleware.

Comment: That is not the case, as I need to forward it to "/" inside Portainer container. This is the behavior I have with Nginx that works fine. Without `stripPrefix` page does not load at all, as I get 404 not found.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Ok, then you need stripprefix the middleware. But if you configure it like as it is above,  the part of the path `/portainer/whatever/whatever/...` will be just removed from the path. if you need to forward `/` into portainer and your prefix should be `portainer` instead of `/portainer`.

Comment: I tried setting `PathPrefix` to `/portainer/` and behavior was the same as with `/portainer`. Then I set it to `portainer` and in all cases I receive 404. I also tried these combinations with `stripprefix` and results were the same.

Comment: I also tried using `RedirectRegex` to redirect user from `http://example.com/portainer` to `http://example.com/portainer/`, but it did not work.

Comment: Can you check what url is forwarded to portainer? I have a kubernetes setup and I tried stripprefix, it works as expected.

Comment: Where can I check it? I'm using only Docker for my setup.

Comment: I updated my post with additional information. I hope this helps clarify my setup.